# Flask project with HTML is not working

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, localhost

I am trying to run this Flask project, put it's not working. Does anyone know why?

The .py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hoofdpagina():
    return render_template("afvink2.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onunload="Reset()"  style="background-color:Pink;">
<head>
                <title>Messenger </title>
        </head>

        <h3>Messenger</h3>
Messagebox:<br> <textarea id="chatbox" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea> <br><br>
<br><input type="text" id="P1" value="ADI" ><input type="text" id="first"><button onclick="B1Function()">Send</button><br><br>
<br><input type="text" id="P2" value="JS" > <input type="text" id="second"><button onclick="B2Function()">Send</button>


<script>
function B1Function() {
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += document.getElementById("P1").value ;
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += ": " ;
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += document.getElementById("first").value ;
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += "\r"
    document.getElementById("first").value = ""

}
function B2Function() {

    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += document.getElementById("P2").value ;
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += ": " ;
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += document.getElementById("second").value ;
    document.getElementById("chatbox").value += "\r"
    document.getElementById("second").value = ""

}
function Reset() {
    document.getElementById("Berichtenbox").value = ""
    document.getElementById("first").value = ""
    document.getElementById("second").value = ""

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The error:

```
C:\...\...\...\
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jun/2017 12:12:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The page http://127.0.0.1:5000/ says:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this the only code you've got? I can run this locally with no issues

Comment: you can try using `app.run(debug=True)` to make server show a debugger in case an exception happened

Comment: can you change your `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)` and repost the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project structure should be this.

```
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── afvink2.html
```

`render_template` method by default looks at the **templates** directory.

You can also configure the directory of templates to **views** or **public**

by simply mentioning the parameter in flask

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="views")
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="path/to/whatever")
```

Do check the configuration flask provides.
Their [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object) is pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks!! Worked :)

Comment: That's good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Flask will look templates in the "templates" directory. Move your html template into the templates dir. It should work

Comment: Thanks! :) Worked!